# How to change v-model value from JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Google autocomplete address form. I found [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) at google official web page. Everything is fine. Everything works! but it's native Javascript,

I have Vue application and I don't like how I change text input values from JS script. **The idea is that when I change something in main input, JS event listener should change values for other inputs:**

```
 document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
```

Problem is that I should use **"document"** to change values:

```
 document.getElementById('street_number').value
```

I would like to have something like tat:

```
 <input type="text" v-model="input.address" ref="addressRef">
```

And to read values:

```
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                input: {
                    address: "",
                    ...
                }

            };
        },
        methods: {
            test() {
                console.log(this.input.address);
                console.log(this.$refs.addressRef);
        }
       }
```

So the question is:

- How to set the value from JS code to update binding values? Right now values **are null because I use "getElementById("id").value = val"**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can emit `input` event afterwards which `v-model` relies on for updating its `value`:

```
let el = document.getElementById("id");
el.value = val;
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

In action:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    message: null
  },
  
  methods: {
    updateBinding() {
      let el = document.getElementById("input");
      el.value = 'Hello!';    
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="updateBinding">Click me </button><br>
  <input id="input" v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">
  <p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks it does not works in [my example](https://gist.github.com/VakhoQ/46de60bf4f26c2686eedf4a87b60390f) Can you help me please?

Comment: @grep `new Event(addressType)` should be `new Event('input')`